# Laravel how to run eloquent queries that are value of an array and passed to the view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Because of a case, I need to store multiple tables eloquent queries to an array and pass them to view, then inside view I should process them. So how can I do that, I have tried with `call_user_func()` and `call_user_func_array()` bot not solved the problem and can't run. bellow is my array of eloquent.

```
$my_eloquent_array = array('course' => 'App\Models\Course::all();',
            'user' => 'App\Models\User::whereHas(
                    \'roles\', function($q){
                    $q->where(\'name\',\'course_coordinator\');
                }
                )->get(array(\'id\',DB::raw(\'CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name\')))'
);
```

So now inside view within a loop how i can run those eloquent array values?

```
$resourceDropdowns = array(
    'curriculum_id'             => array('query' => 'App\Models\ProfessionalDevelopment\Curriculum::all(\'id\',\'name\')', 'label' => 'Curriculum'),
    'classroom_id'              => array('query' => 'Classroom::all(\'id\',\'no\')', 'label' => 'Classroom'),
    'training_coordinator_id'   => array('query' => 'User::whereHas(
                    \'roles\', function($q){
                    $q->where(\'name\',\'course_coordinator\');
                }
                )->get(array(\'id\',DB::raw(\'CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name\')))', 'label' => 'Training Coordinator'),
    'focal_point_id'            => array('query' => 'User::whereHas(
                    \'roles\', function($q){
                    $q->where(\'name\',\'focal_point\');
                }
                )->get(array(\'id\',DB::raw(\'CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name\')))', 'label' => 'Focal Point'),
    'master_trainer_id'         => array('query' => 'User::whereHas(
                    \'roles\', function($q){
                    $q->where(\'name\',\'master_trainer\');
                }
                )->get(array(\'id\',DB::raw(\'CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name\')))', 'label' => 'Master Trainer'),
    'stage_id'                  => array('query' => 'Stage::all(\'id\',\'no\')', 'label' => 'Stage'),
    'stream_id'                 => array('query' => 'Stream::all(\'id\',\'no\')', 'label' => 'Stream'),
    'unit_id'                   => array('query' => 'Unit::all(\'id\',\'no\')', 'label' => 'Unit'),
);;
        if(count($resourceDropdowns) > 0){
            $dropDownFilters = array();
            foreach($resourceDropdowns as $drop_key => $drop_val){
                $dropDownFilters[$drop_key]['query'] = $drop_val['query'];
                $dropDownFilters[$drop_key]['label'] = $drop_val['label'];
            }

        }
```

But `$drop_val['query']` not running, its just an string in final array.

Comment: Yes it is a string. Because you have put  ' ' around it. And without it you will get error message. So this is not your solution.

Comment: Try the way as I suggested to you and let me know if you face any problem in it.

Comment: @RaviHirani Based on my need I have set eloquent query array inside my models based on model needs, and then in interface when user select a table, with an ajax request i want to get selected table eloquent query array and pass the result to the view. it means it's not possible for me to make that array inside controller.

Comment: Then encode it. base_64 encode will help you.

Comment: @RaviHirani Inside model? but in model it says that `expression is not allowed as field default value`

Comment: You can make  functions to get your query data. Like to get classroom data you can user getClassRoomData() method. create this method in your Classroom model and put this function in your array such as  'classroom_id'  =>   getClassRoomData();

Comment: I have completely understand your situation. Now According to me, there is only one solution in PHP world that is eval(). Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the same code by this way.

```
$cources = App\Models\Course::all();
$users =  App\Models\User::whereHas(
                    'roles', function($q){
                    $q->where('name','course_coordinator');
                }
                )->get(array('id',DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS full_name')));

$my_eloquent_array = array('course' => $cources,
            'user' => $users
); 

return view('VIEW_NAME', ['data' => $my_eloquent_array]);
```

Replace `$drop_val['query']` with `eval($drop_val['query'])`

**Note**:- When you are using eval() function always put semicolon(;) at the end of each string. In your case you must write

```
array('query'=>'App\Models\Course::all();');
```

If this code is not working then try this way:-

```
$arr = array('query'=>base64_encode(App\Models\Course::all()));
$user = base64_decode($arr['query']);
```

Comment: Yeah, it is not the problem with code, my question is that how to run `$users` inside view?

Comment: When I use like `call_user_func($users);` gives this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all('id','name')() `, and without `call_user_func()` just print the eloquent query string.

Comment: @jones: Please check my updated answer. here VIEW_NAME is your blade template and you can print data in blade file as {{ $data }}

Comment: You do not need to call call_user_func function. I am not exactly understand why do you need to call this function?

Comment: You can directly get query result in object and pass that object to your view. and in your view file you need to simply print it.

Comment: I have update my question like the things you suggested, but eloquent query is not running.

Comment: With `eval($drop_val['query'])` no things occur and the final array query index is empty. I also added `;`

Comment: result of `eval($drop_val['query'])` is empty

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works but you could try it. I would try storing the function and executing it while looping over them:

```
// We store the queries with its associated parameters
$queries = [ ["query" => App\Models\Course::all, "params" => null ]];

// We loop over the functions to be executed
foreach($queries as $query){

    // Now, we execute the function
    $query["query"]($query["params"])->get();
}
```

I am not sure if this example works, but I would recommend you an approach like this.

You'd have to think about a good solution for passing complex parameters to the function.

Comment: The problem with your code is that in my case I should store `App\Models\Course::all` as string inside array, because I should create that array inside models.